# C# regexp matched subexpressions returns empty string

Tags: c#, regex, string, pattern-matching

I wrote this regexp:

```
var cellPattern = new Regex(@"(?(?=\d+)\d+|\|)\s(.)\s", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

And to get cells from this string:

```
string field = 
"  A   B   C   D   E \n" +
"1   | X |   |   |   \n" +
" ---+---+---+---+---\n" +
"2   |   |   |   |   \n" +
" ---+---+---+---+---\n" +
"3   | O |   |   |   \n" +
" ---+---+---+---+---\n" +
"4   |   |   | X |   \n" +
" ---+---+---+---+---\n" +
"5   |   |   |   |   \n" +
"O >>> ";
```

I'm executing `cellPattern.Matches(field);` It returns MatchCollection with 25 matches, **but why all matches has an empty string as first group?**

*P.S.:
If I am using a named matched subexpressions, everything works the way I want: all matches has grid cell as "cell" group*:

```
var cellPattern = new Regex(@"(?(?=\d+)\d+|\|)\s(?<cell>.)\s", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

*P.P.S: My project framework is `.NET Framework 4.5.2`*

*P.P.P.S: On [this site](http://regexstorm.net/tester), you also can see this behavior*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in .NET framework. Then using `(?(?= ) )`, it ignores the content of the next group, but it still counts towards the number of groups.

When it sees `(?(` it sets a flag to ignore the next group, expecting to see `(?(expression) ... | ... )`, but instead there is a `(?= ... )`, so the flag is not reset until the next capture group.

A fix would be to name the group, add a dummy group:

```
(?(?=\d+)\d+|\|)()\s(.)\s
```

or add another level of parens:

```
(?((?=\d+))\d+|\|)\s(.)\s
```

In this case, you could also remove the conditional:

```
(?:\d+|\|)()\s(.)\s
```

Comment: Thanks for explanation! Also I have already simplified regex to `@"[\d|] (.) "`, but this is off topic